# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (foo) specified for MyModel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

*Documenting my own mistake. Hope this could help others !*

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50),
    bar = models.IntegerField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Error during system check:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (foo) specified for MyModel
```

Whereas the field `foo` is defined on `MyModel`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, you caught it, there is a coma at the end of the line `foo = models.CharField(max_length=50),` that should be removed in order to make the field recognized by Django.